# Exclude some words from tweets using java

Tags: java, twitter

I'm trying to write a program that retrieve tweets from a specific user and the count the most used words. in my code i get each word written in the user timeline besides the number of repetition. but i only need to get the most used words and the count.

how can i fix my code to do so?

```
for(Status status2 : status){
    status2.getText();
    //System.out.println(status2.getCreatedAt());

    String s = status2.toString();
    String[] splitted = s.split(" ");
    HashMap hm = new HashMap();
    int x;  

    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
        if (!hm.containsKey(splitted[i])) {
            hm.put(splitted[i], 1);
        } else {
            hm.put(splitted[i], (Integer) hm.get(splitted[i]) + 1);
        }
        for (Object word : hm.keySet()){
            System.out.println(word + " " + (Integer) hm.get(word));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which one do you want? 1) Most used word in one status 2) most used word in timeline

Comment: timeline(user's tweets)

Answer (score 2):

I did this using a `list` of `String` variables, but the same concept applies for tweets. Just loop over each tweet and get the `String` that the message was, instead of looping over the `String` variables in the `List` object.

- Initialize your `map` outside of your loop of tweets. When you initialize it inside your `loop`, it will recreate the map for each tweet. This will erase any data you found.
- Output the values from your `map` outside of looping through tweets. Otherwise you will output the data on every tweet iteration. This may be desired results, but from what I gather it is not what you are looking for.
- Quality of life type update, but you should use a `foreach` loop to loop over your split array. No need to use the extra memory for the `int` counter.

The issue with your results was that you were recreating the map through each iteration, wiping out all previous data. If you initialize the map before the loop, and don't re-initialize each iteration, you can keep track of the data throughout all of the tweets. Example of doing this is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<String> statusTweets = new ArrayList<String>();
    statusTweets.add("At the bar");
    statusTweets.add("At the house");
    statusTweets.add("Out with friends");

    Map<String,Integer> wordHits = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    for(String status : statusTweets){
        String[] statusSplitOnSpace = status.split(" ");
        for(String wordInStatus : statusSplitOnSpace){
            if (!wordHits.containsKey(wordInStatus)) {
                wordHits.put(wordInStatus, 1);
            } else {
                wordHits.put(wordInStatus, wordHits.get(wordInStatus)+1);
            }
        }
    }

    for(Entry<String,Integer> wordHit : wordHits.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("Word (" + wordHit.getKey() + ") was found " + wordHit.getValue() + " times.");
    }

}
```

After the loop, you can do what you need with the data you found. Find the higher word count, remove certain words, etc. I just made a loop to output results. Which gave me:

```
Word (the) was found 2 times.
Word (with) was found 1 times.
Word (bar) was found 1 times.
Word (At) was found 2 times.
Word (house) was found 1 times.
Word (friends) was found 1 times.
Word (Out) was found 1 times.
```

Comment: That's good. many thanks. but i want to display the most used words and ignore the rest which are less used. and to exclude some words like "the, a, an, but, etc.."

Comment: First off, I'd recommend some reading up on variable naming practices.  Your variable naming needs a lot of work.  Mike's answer has much better naming of variables.

You can take his answer and process the wordHits map to display whatever information you see fit.

For example, you can elect not to print any words that have characters fewer than 4.  Also, you could only print words that are within X percentage of the most common word.  Or out of all the words that are valid, only display the top 20% common.

Comment: @AfnanHumdan use the map of the words to do whatever you want with them. If you want to remove the word "the", use `wordHits.remove("the")`. If you want to get the top 3 words, order the list based on the value and take the top 3. Once you have parsed the data you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I appreciate your patience Mike, but how can i make a list like that?

Comment: @AfnanHumdan you will have to be more specific, a list like what? If you're looking for a list of common words to remove, it would be arbitrary. Do some googling and find some, there is no hard set rule.

Comment: I meant a list based on the value

Comment: @AfnanHumdan a list of what based on the value of what? You have a `map` that contains the word (the key) and the amount of times it occurred over their entire feed (the value) in my example.

Comment: the value based on the time the words occured

Comment: @AfnanHumdan if you need the map reversed (number of times occurred is the key, word is the value) then just loop through the current map and create a new one using it.